# remove css image border on child page

Tags: css, image

I'm using asp.net with themes, master and child pages.  In the base css, I've got the img tag with a border.  It's great in that I never have to place a border around my image.  However, on one page where I'm using the Nivo slider, I want to remove the border.  I know it's the base image, cause if I change the border to white, everything works fine - but every image on my website then is missing the border.  I thought the inheritance went theme, page, inline css?

```
 img { margin:0 10px 10px 10px;border:1px solid #000000;}
 #imgNoLine { margin:0 0 0 0;border:0 #ffffff !important; }

 #maincontainer #contentwrapper #contentcolumn #contentInnerTube fieldset .nivoSlider img { position:absolute;margin:0 0 0 0; top:0px;left:0px; display:none;border:none 0 solid white !important; }

 <img src="image.jpg" alt="" style="border-width: 0 !important;" id="imgNoLine" />
```

Comment: in inline style use border:none and there is no point to set !important

Comment: Doesn't that image have an id or class name? If not, can't you apply one to it?

Comment: I did try in the inline style of border:none;  no change.

Comment: It does - the id="imgNoLine" - see above.  I tried applying and got no result. I'm with you - this is really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

put your slider in a div and give the div an id.then use this in css:

```
#div-id img{
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: The slider is already in a div (please not included code above).  However, the css is applied to the img tag, so removing the border above has not affect - I tried it.  Dang.